# Windows Service does not execute in release mode C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Windows service (in Visual Studio 2008), which works when I run it in debug mode:

```
        static void Main()
    {
        #if DEBUG
           Descarga myServicio = new Descarga();
           myServicio.OnDebug();
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        #else

           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
           ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Descarga() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
       #endif

    }
```

The `OnDebugStart()` just calls the `OnStart()` method of the Windows service and the thread that runs is just a thread that runs infinitely (until the `OnStop()` is called) to check if the service is still alive & online.

```
    public Timer myTimer;
    public string fileName;
    string txtLog;

    public Descarga()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Interval = 10000; 
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);   
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myTimer.Enabled = true;            
    }
```

This works perfectly fine when I start it in debug mode, but when I run it in release, the service gets hosted, but the code doesn't execute.

I changed the users of the service and the problem continues.

Kind regards

Comment: Which `Timer` class do you use?

Comment: @ToniWenzel - from context, it would appear to be [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Other FX Timer classes have different properties/callback concepts.

Comment: When you run it as a release/service - do you get a message along the lines of "the service started but then stopped..."?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your code,

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    myTimer.Enabled = true;            
}
```

Your `OnStart` is starting the timer. When in release mode, you are not calling that and your timer which I assume is driving the service isn't getting started. You'll need to call that as well in release mode.